# What is this this square hole in bathroom rough in used for?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, rough-in

I have a plumbing rough in that is located below grade in my basement. The system consists of a 2" sewer pipe and a toilet rough in connected to an ejecter tank. In the middle there is what appears to be a french drain that is open to the ground. Not sure what it is for and if I can cover it up when I finish the bathroom?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's for a shower drain. It's common to leave an opening about that size to allow for slight variation in tub position, manipulation of the trap assembly, etc. You should find a stub under the dirt. Normally you'd remove the lumber, which was a temporary concrete form.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should have cleared out the dirt first....

Comment: Ok your were spot on. There is another 2 or 2 1/2" pipe underneath the dirt that must T into the ejecter tank. So.. what's the best way to cover this (I'm only going to make a half bath)? Short of concreting over it, to leave the option of adding it later.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in the comments thread. Ask in a new post, and mention what you'll be using for flooring.